# Looping every time event click Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I created code which just shows the capability on event click and etc.

I am facing difficulty handle the event.

Can anyone help me, which part that I've made a mistake. Because whenever I click on the event it always repeating simultaneously. Assume that I click for the first time the alert will only appear once, when I click the second time the alert will show twice times.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#button').click(function (e) { // Button which will activate our modal
    $('#modal').reveal({ // The item which will be opened with reveal
      animation: 'fade', // fade, fadeAndPop, none
      animationspeed: 600, // how fast animtions are
      closeonbackgroundclick: true, // if you click background will modal close?
      // the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
      dismissmodalclass: 'close'
    });

    $("#gag").click(function () {
      alert('This event will trigger only once!');
    });
    $("#fug").click(function () {
      alert('This event will trigger only twice!');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you clicking #button input element twice? If this is so it #gag and #fug input element's click will be registered twice and it goes on.

Comment: Why are you registering the gag and fug click handlers from inside the button click handler?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click(function(e) { // Button which will activate our modal
        $( "#gag" )
            .unbind()
            .click(
                function() { 
                    alert('This event will trigger only once!'); 
                });
        $( "#fug" )
            .unbind()
            .click(
                function() { 
                    alert('This event will trigger only twice!'); 
                });
    });
});
```

This will first `unbind()` then `bind()` and so will not duplicate your events

Comment: I still got the function repeated all the times